# How does ANSI_NULLS work in TSQL?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, null

`SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` seems to give different results in TSQL depending on whether you're comparing a field from a table or a value. Can anyone help me understand why the last 2 of my queries give no results? I'm not looking for a solution, just an explanation.

```
select 1 as 'Col' into #a
select NULL as 'Col' into #b

--This query gives results, as expected.  
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
select * from #b
where NULL = Col

--This query gives results, as expected.
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
select * from #a
where NULL != Col

--This workaround gives results, too.
select * from #a a, #b b
where isnull(a.Col, '') != isnull(b.Col, '')

--This query gives no results, why?
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
select * from #a a, #b b
where a.Col != b.Col

--This query gives no results, why?
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
select * from #a a, #b b
where b.Col != a.Col
```

Comment: I've only just stumbled across this and I find it concerning I never knew this before. I always thought SQL behaved the same way as comparisons to NULL in Java/.NET etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason the last two queries fail is that `SET ANSI_NULLS ON/OFF` only applies when you are comparing against a variable or the NULL value. It does not apply when you are comparing column values. From the BOL:

> SET ANSI_NULLS ON affects a comparison
>   only if one of the operands of the
>   comparison is either a variable that
>   is NULL or a literal NULL. If both
>   sides of the comparison are columns or
>   compound expressions, the setting does
>   not affect the comparison.

Comment: @rossfabricant - The ability to disable ANSI_NULLS is only possible for backwards compatibility (I.e., the reasons for ever setting it off can be counted on one hand with fingers left over). So, I suspect that the reasons must be because of older implementations of SQL that operated this way.

Answer (score 0):

Anything compared to a null value fails.  Even comparing two null values will fail.  Even the != will fail because of the (IMHO) stupid handling of NULL.

That said, the != queries could be rewritten to say:

```
select * from #a a where a.Col not in (select b.Col from #b b)
```

The last query is identical to the second to last query as the order of the comparison doesn't matter.

Incidentally, your workaround works simply because you are testing for a null value in the #b.Col column and explicitly converting it to a '' which then allows your query to do a string compare between them.  An alternative way of writing that would be:

```
select * from #a a, #b b
where a.Col != COALESCE(b.Col, '')
```