# T-SQL: What is NOT(1=NULL)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ansi-nulls

I don't get the simple boolean algebra on my sql-server. According to msdn, the following statement should return "1", but on my server it returns "0".
Can you help me?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SELECT CASE WHEN NOT(1=NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Please have a look at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175118%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). There it clearly states: "Comparing NULL to a non-NULL value always results in FALSE." - no matter what the ANSI_NULLS-setting is. Thus "1=NULL" should be FALSE and NOT(FALSE) should thus be TRUE and the statement should return "1".

But on my machine, it returns "0"!

One explanation might be, that "1=NULL" evaluates to "UNKNOWN". NOT(UNKNOWN) is still UNKNOWN ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189455.aspx)), which would force the CASE-Statement into the ELSE.

But then the official documentation of the equals-operator would be wrong. I cannot believe this!

Can anybody explain this behaviour?

Thank you very much for any help!

Edit (2012-03-15):

One thing I just found that might be of interest for some of you:

```
CREATE TABLE #FooTest (Value INT)
ALTER TABLE #FooTest WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ccFooTestValue CHECK (Value>1)
PRINT '(NULL>1) = ' + CASE WHEN NULL>1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
INSERT INTO #FooTest (Value) VALUES (NULL)
```

The print-Statement writes 'False', but the insertion runs without error.
SQL-Server seems to negate the check-constraint in order to search for rows that do not fulfill the constraint-check:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE NOT(Value>NULL)) <Generate error>
```

Since the check-constraint evaluates to UNKNOWN, the negation is also UNKNOWN and SqlServer does not find any row violating the check-constraint.

Comment: Your `UNKNOWN` version of explanation works for me perfectly well, and so I conclude that you've answered your own question. Unless, of course, you wanted us to explain *their* behaviour. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MSDN page for Equals that you link to definitely appears incorrect.

Check the MSDN page for [SET ANSI_NULLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx).

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, all comparisons against a null value
>   evaluate to UNKNOWN.

To get that example SQL statement to work as expected, you should use compare using ["IS NULL" or "IS NOT NULL"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933227.aspx) instead of using the equals operator (=). For example:

`SELECT CASE WHEN NOT(1 IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

OR

`SELECT CASE WHEN (1 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: Thank you for the other source that seems to describe the behaviour correctly. I simply could not believe that msdn is really wrong on such a very basic topic. But msdn being inconsistent in itself on this topic is enough for me. Thanks, question answered :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes that link is wrong. File a documentation bug on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback).

Sql uses three valued logic not boolean logic. `true`, `false`, and `unknown`

Most comparison operators (i.e. excluding `IS [NOT] NULL`) involving `NULL` result in `unknown` not `True` or `False`. Negating unknown yields unknown as per the truth tables [shown here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic).

Answer (score 2):

You want to read the [documentation on `ANSI_NULLS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx). SQL actually implements a ternary logic, not boolean logic, where a comparison operation can result in true, false or undefined.  Basically, this means that the explanation you proffered is correct.

This can be demonstrated with the following query:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SELECT CASE
  WHEN (1=NULL) THEN 0
  WHEN NOT(1=NULL) THEN 1    
  ELSE -1
END
```

Which results in `-1` on my machine (SQL Server 2005 Enterprise). Changing the first line to `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` produces `1` as expected.

So, is the official documentation wrong? I'd submit that is somewhat misleading. It says that it results in FALSE. Obviously this is wrong. What the documentation meant to say is that comparing a non-null to NULL always results in a mismatch whose value also depends on `ANSI_NULLS`.

Of course, [on SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), the `ANSI_NULLS` setting has been removed, and therefore setting it any which way will not change the result.

Answer (score 2):

It's not boolean logic, its trinary logic: {True, False, I Don't Know.} Break it down this way:

```
IF 1=NULL
    print 'True'
else
    print 'False'
```

Generates `False` because `1=NULL` equals `NULL`, aka "not True"

```
IF not(1=NULL)
    print 'True'
else
    print 'False'
```

Also generates `False` because `not(1=NULL)` equals `not(NULL)` equals `NULL`, aka "not True". This gets you to

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NOT(1=NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

which as per above is the same as

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

which, since `NULL` is not true, resovles to the `ELSE` clause.

In short, as far as I'm concerned the documentation is incorrect. Distressing, but not unique, and so not entirely surprising.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) in a subquery, it uses 2 valued logic and will give you the true/false you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From BOL (credit to [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2866860/413180)):

> SET ANSI_NULLS ON affects a comparison only if one of the operands of
>   the comparison is either a variable that is NULL or a literal NULL. If
>   both sides of the comparison are columns or compound expressions, the
>   setting does not affect the comparison.

So I guess the `NOT` operation is checking `1=NULL` which is unknown and because this is not a variable or literal NULL gets the ELSE part of your comparison as you hypothesised.

Answer (score 0):

1=NULL seems to return FALSE only when ANSI_NULLS is OFF. Otherwise it's indeterminate. The msdn page probably needs to be edited to clarify that point.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
SELECT CASE WHEN (1=NULL) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false or unknown' END --returns false or unknown
, CASE WHEN NOT(1=NULL) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false or unknown' END --returns true
go

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SELECT CASE WHEN (1=NULL) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false or unknown' END --returns false or unknown
, CASE WHEN NOT(1=NULL) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false or unknown' END --returns false or unknown
go
```